# How to configure Pound proxy to pass requests to .well-known directory?

Tags: reverse-proxy, pound

I use Pound proxy in front of Apache, so Pound listens to port 80 and Apache - to port 8888, and I am now trying to figure out how to configure Pound to pass requests to /home/username/public_html/.well-known for seamless Let's Encrypt generation and renewal. Like it can be done with nginx as discussed on [Exclude Let's Encrypt http requests from nginx https redirect](https://serverfault.com/questions/845254/exclude-lets-encrypt-http-requests-from-nginx-https-redirect), [Lets Encrypt with an nginx reverse proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/768509/lets-encrypt-with-an-nginx-reverse-proxy) or https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/404-on-well-known-acme-challenge/15565/15.

Unfortunately, the documentation on http://www.apsis.ch/pound does not mention any proxy pass directives. Could anyone recommend how to configure Pound to pass requests to certain directories?

My configuration for now is something like:

```
ListenHTTP
  Address 1.2.3.4
  Port 80

  Service
      HeadRequire "Host:.*some1.myserver.net.*"
      Redirect "https://some1.myserver.net"
  End

  Service
      HeadRequire "Host:.*some2.myserver.net.*"
      Redirect "https://some2.myserver.net"
  End
End

ListenHTTPS
  Address 1.2.3.4
  Port    443

  # first domain
  Cert "/etc/pki/tls/letsencrypt_pound/pound_some1.pem"
  # second domain
  Cert "/etc/pki/tls/letsencrypt_pound/pound_some2.pem"

  Disable SSLv3
End
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of serving directory, you can pass http request to web server integrated into letsencrypt. Just add service (before regular service rules) like:

```
Service
  URL "/.well-known/acme-challenge/"
  IgnoreCase 1
  BackEnd
    Address 127.0.0.1
    Port 8180
  End
End
```

And then invoke letsencrypt like:

```
letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone --http-01-port 8180 --standalone-supported-challenges http-01 -d domain1.com -d domain2.com -d www.domain1.com
```

etc (configuration from my old snippet for letsencrypt, for certbot there should be something simmilar). After that for renew - if you don't change list of supported domains - use just letsencrypt-auto renew.